# How to Create Histogram Program where user enters all line lengths

Tags: java

The title is not so informative but basically I have made a histogram program that will ask the user for number of lines and how many asterisks in each line. The problem is I need the lines to come up all at once, adjacent to eachother, but after every input for how many asterisks in a line it will print out the line like this:

```
Type in num of stars: 4.7
***** 4.7
Type in num of stars: 2.1
** 2.1
```

The other problem is that I am using one variable to store the number of stars, so I don't think it's possible to print all at once as the variable can only hold one value. Is there a possible solution for this? Maybe using arrays? The code is down here

```
import java.awt.*;
import hsa.Console;

public class Methods_5
{
static Console c;           // The output console

public static void main (String[] args)
{
    c = new Console ();

    histogram ();
} // main method


public static void histogram ()
{
    c.print ("How many lines do you want in the histogram? ");
    int max = c.readInt ();


    for (int i = 0 ; i < max ; i++)
    {
        c.print ("Type in the value for this line: ");
        double num = c.readDouble ();
        int x = 0;
        int y = (int) Math.round (num);
        while (x < y)
        {
            c.print ("*");
            x++;
        }
        c.println (num);

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Yes, either an array (which you'll have to resize if the data don't fit) or a `List` (that will grow as you need).

Answer (score 0):

```
c.print("How many lines do you want in the histogram? ");
int max = c.readInt();
//declare array of the same size, catch exception if user inputs string

int[] totalSize = new int[max];
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
//store all the values in total size array.
for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
 c.print("Type in the value for this line: ");
 double num = c.readDouble();
 y = (int) Math.round(num);
 totalSize[i] = y;
}
//print all the values at once;
for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
 x = 0;
 y = totalSize[i];
    while (x < y) {
      c.print("*");
      x++;
    }
 c.println(num);
}
```

- Store the values and an array.
- Iterate over the new array.